# Issue with installing Windows-10 on new SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bios, bootloader, windows-installation

I have bought a new SATA SSD for my old Dell inspiron N4050 laptop. I have replaced the HDD with the SSD. Now when I'm trying to install windows 10 on the SSD from the bootable PD (1), it doesn't show anything and gives a blank screen (2), after that if press any key then it restarts (3).

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]

I have also tried different patches of windows 10 including 1909 and the one from the latest windows website.

I have also tried windows 8.1 but the same issue persists for windows OS.

(**Please Note:** The windows setup is working correctly as I have checked that on my new Laptop from the boot menu,
The SSD is also working: I have checked the SSD in diagnostics and it shows up, I even installed Ubuntu now to check and it works flawlessly.
The SATA configuration is set AHCI, and also I have reset to defaults in the boot menu.
)

I have installed windows 10 on this laptop 2-3 times and it didn't have any issues on HDD. Now after replacing that with SSD I couldn't install windows anymore. Please help me to resolve this issue!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some older systems do not support UEFI(Unified Extensible Firmware Interface ) .while preparing a bootable pendrive with rufus or power iso or with any other apllication try changing partitioning scheme to MBR(master boot record) instead of GPT(guid partion table),it might work. Otherwise it should have been problem with BIOS settings.
if that does not work,try disabling safe boot and enable legacy boot in BIOS setting

Comment: Thanks man, that solved the problem!!

Comment: @Ajay kumar what part of his answer solved your issue. Remember, problems happen to other people too, so share the right solution, please. Txs.

Comment: @H_7 Hey, Really sorry for a year late reply, In my case changing partition to MBR instead of GPT when making bootable pendrive worked. I didnt had to change anything else